# Java Stream stateful behavior example

Tags: java, parallel-processing, synchronization, java-stream

The [package summary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) of `java.util.stream` states the following:

> An example of a stateful lambda is the parameter to `map()` in:
>
> ```
> Set<Integer> seen = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());
> stream.parallel().map(e -> { if (seen.add(e)) return 0; else return e; })...
> ```
>
> Here, if the mapping operation is performed in parallel, the results for the same input could vary from run to run, due to thread scheduling differences, whereas, with a stateless lambda expression the results would always be the same.

I don't understand why this wouldn't produce consistent results, given that the set is synchronized and can only process one element at a time. Can you complete the above example in a way that demonstrates how the result could vary due to parallelization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<Integer> numbers = // fill it in with [1, 3, 3, 5]
List<Integer> collected = numbers.stream().parallel().map(...).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`collected` could contain either [0, 0, 3, 0] or [0, 3, 0, 0], depending on which of the middle two elements was processed first.

Comment: I forgot that parallel streams can still preserve encounter order. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, it's zeroing out unseen elements, so there would be three 0's in the result.

Comment: @shmosel Whoops, got the direction of the `if` backwards. Fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this counts as a stateful per-se (if it does not I'll just delete this), but relying on *anything* that has state inside `map` and the like is bad.

```
int[] arr = new int[3];
    Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
            .map(i -> {
                arr[i] = i + 5;
                return i * 2;
            })
            .count();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

In jdk-9 this will produce an array with zeroes only, since there are no operations that change the Stream size (`flatmap` or `filter`), thus `map` is never executed.

Comment: Interesting point, but not directly relevant to the question.